# JSP fmt:FormatDate 3 Days into the Future

Tags: java, jsp, date, format

I wish to call the current date:

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
```

And display it

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MMMMM d, yyyy" />
```

But then display the date 3 days later

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MMMMM d+3, yyyy" />
```

What's the proper syntax for displaying todays date + 3, becuase the above only displays:

```
September 18+3, 2014
```

Comment: use should update value of `now` variable not the `pattern`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<c:set target="${now}" property="time" value="${now.time + 86400000 * 3}" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MMMMM d, yyyy" />
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to JSP and Server-side scripting... why the 8640000?

Comment: It is number of millseconds in a day. now.time is returning number of milliseconds since 1.1.1970, and 86400000 * 3 adds three more days :-)

Comment: you method makes complete sense as to WHY it would work... but I continue to get an error: **javax.servlet.ServletException: Attempt to coerce a value of type "java.lang.Long" to type "java.util.Date"**

Comment: I missed one important point: you cannot call fmt:formatDate on any other object but on java.util.Date, so you have to use c:set to increase date.

Comment: how the heck do I do that?!?!  I'm fairly new to JSP and Server-side scripting.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see if it works for you. There are other ways to do it: create variable in Servlet or MVC controller (depends are you using plain JSP/Servlets or some kind of MVC framework such as Spring MVC), create your own tag library that knows how to increase date... Depends on your use case, application setup and libraries you use.

Comment: **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "time"**

Comment: LOL.. no worries, but I'm back to the **java.lang.Long** error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61526/discussion-between-magic-wand-and-murphy1976).